# What is the opposite of an escalating balls-up?

Tags: slang, idiom-requests

An informal idiom in Britain is an *escalating balls-up*

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escalating)
> *escalating*
> escalate, intransitive verb
> : to increase in extent, volume, number, amount, intensity, or scope

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balls-up)
> *balls-up* noun
> British, informal + sometimes offensive
> FOUL-UP

Thus, the phrase refers to something going wrong and getting even worse as time progresses. It may have its origin in the idea of a malfunctioning mechanical ball governor:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_governor#/media/File:Centrifugal_governor.png)
> centrifugal "fly-ball" governor. The balls swing out as speed increases, which closes the valve, until a balance is achieved between demand and the proportional gain of the linkage and valve

As the balls rise, the malfunctioning governor might increase rather than decrease engine speed, leading to a disastrous consequence. Or the idiom is sometimes understood to have offensive sexual connotations; this may explain difficulty in finding literary reference to the idiom.

Whatever the origin of the phrase, it refers to a series of actions and events, each worsening the situation.

For example: *The more the teacher shouted at the class, the worse their behaviour became, and the more he shouted; it was an escalating balls-up*

My question is to ask if there is a popular idiom that expresses the opposite - that the more time passes and the more things happen, the better things get?

For example, *The more she praised the artist the better his paintings became, so she praised them even more and he was eventually encouraged to enter his work in national competitions; it was …………*

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their reason? Otherwise it looks like inexplicable spite.

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps you could include a sample sentence or two for each of "escalating balls-up" and your request (with a blank for that one, obviously) showing how the expressions might be used in practice. "Opposite" is a very loose term.

Comment: @AndrewLeach sounds reasonable. Will edit later.

Comment: The opposite of balls up would be normality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try ***virtuous circle***

Defined in [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtuous%20circle) as:

> a chain of events in which one desirable occurrence leads to another which further promotes the first occurrence and so on resulting in a continuous process of improvement

Comment: Three professional linguists and I are chagrined that we all forgot this term. It might also be the opposite of "a vicious spiral". Thankyou for taking a serious question seriously and for your authoritative and apt answer.